# SyntaxError: missing } after property list [Break On This Error] });

Tags: jquery

Please can someone help me with that syntax? Firebug keeps on telling me error no mather what I tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".custompage").click(function () {
        var Splitter = (this.id).split("-");
        var thepage = Splitter[1];
        $("#myblock").slideUp();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "userpagesajax.php",
            data: {
                pageid: thepage,
                siteid: "' . $siteid . '"
            },
            success: function (Response) {
                $("#myblock").slideDown(Response);
            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: Is it that hard to count `}`??? It even says missing `}`...

Comment: @Christoph Yes... yes it is. It's even harder to use a code editor with bracket matching that will flat-out tell you when the number of brackets don't match. It's far easier to humiliate yourself on Stack Overflow by posting such a question XD

Comment: @Kolink well, after all it's Stackoverflows fault - they dont provide any syntax-highligting, bracket-matching nor developer console which prompts an unmistakable message while pasting your code in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".custompage").click(function () {
        var Splitter = (this.id).split("-");
        var thepage = Splitter[1];
        $("#myblock").slideUp();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "userpagesajax.php",
            data: {
                pageid: thepage,
                siteid: "' . $siteid . '"
            },
            success: function (Response) {
                $("#myblock").slideDown(Response);
            } // you had an extra );
        });
    });
}); // you were not closing .ready
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the ajax options with `}`

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "userpagesajax.php",
            data: {
                pageid: thepage,
                siteid: "' . $siteid . '"
            },
            success: function (Response) {
                $("#myblock").slideDown(Response);
            } // <-- Success function block closed here
        }); //<-- Ajax options closed here along with ajax method brackets.
```

One easiest way to figure out is using browser itself, click on the the console where error is displayed it will take you to the line that is causing the error and hence the clue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".custompage").click(function () {
        var Splitter = (this.id).split("-");
        var thepage = Splitter[1];
        $("#myblock").slideUp();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "userpagesajax.php",
            data: {
                pageid: thepage,
                siteid: "' . $siteid . '"
            },
            success: function (Response) {
                $("#myblock").slideDown(Response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".custompage").click(function () {
        var Splitter = (this.id).split("-");
        var thepage = Splitter[1];
        $("#myblock").slideUp();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "userpagesajax.php",
            data: {
                pageid: thepage,
                siteid: "' . $siteid . '"
            },
            success: function (Response) {
                $("#myblock").slideDown(Response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This should work.  Just misplaced parentheses and close braces.

By the way, use this website in the future.  I use it whenever I have a small bug I can't spot on my own.

http://jsfiddle.net/

You can hit JSHint and it'll highlight where errors might be.  It will also highlight parentheses and close braces as green or red depending on if they're closed or not.

Comment: this is used to load pages dynamically. Since I am using jquery 1.3.2 I had to change it to live $(".custompage").live("click",function()